# What to do with unused feature branches

Tags: git, merge

After coding, branching and merching I came to this point I ´ve created two implementations for the same problem, that means two feature branches too. I´ve picked my favorite one and merged it with main and deleted this branch which is merged with main. The other implementation (second branch) is not planned for merging with main. I want to hold this branch in background, so is there any git command or a convention how to handle branches in this situation???

Comment: You can just leave branch as it is. Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no convention here; it's entirely up to you.

If there's value in keeping the branch around then by all means keep it, i.e. do nothing about it. Git itself doesn't have any built-in branch purging so the branch will just stick around forever unless you actively do something about it.

If there's no value in keeping the branch around then you can delete it.